# zlib.js Error code: "Z_DATA_ERROR" errno: -3

Tags: node.js, zip, extract, deflate

When i try to extract one file using node.js with package node-stream-zip its getting error like
code: "Z_DATA_ERROR"
errno: -3
message: "too many length or distance symbols"
stack: "Error: too many length or distance symbols↵    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:168:17)"
i analyzed my file compression method which is Deflate64 in my knowledge node-stream-zip package only supporting Deflate64 (compression type : 9 )

here is my code.

```
const StreamZip = require('node-stream-zip');

exports.unzip = function (zipPath, targetDir, completeHandler, progressHandler, errHandler) {
    const zip = new StreamZip({
        file: zipPath,
        storeEntries: true,
    });
    var me = this;
    me.createDirIfNotExist(targetDir);

    zip.on('error', (error) => {
        if (errHandler) {
            console.log(error)
            errHandler(error);
        }
    });

    zip.on('ready', () => {
        me.createDirIfNotExist(targetDir);
        const entries = zip.entries();

        const totalEntries = Object.keys(entries).length;
        let extractedEntries = 0;

        for (const entryName in entries) {
            const entry = entries[entryName];
            zip.extract(entry.name, `${targetDir}/${entry.name}`, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (errHandler) {
                        console.log(err)
                        errHandler(err);
                    }
                } else {
                    extractedEntries++;
                    if (progressHandler) {
                        const progress = (extractedEntries / totalEntries) * 100;
                        progressHandler();
                    }
                    if (extractedEntries === totalEntries) {
                        zip.close();
                        if (completeHandler) {
                            completeHandler();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

i need to extract Deflate64 method files in node.js using any package.
i tried
node-stream-zip,
unzipper,
decompress-zip,
adm-zip,
jszip